# Method parameter as varargs of List

Tags: list, variadic-functions

I have defined a vararg for list as below in method definition ,

```
List<String>... valuesList
```

For example,the below method is to create a sql query with 'where clause' conditions as an input by user.

```
getRecords(List<String> dbColumnList,List<String>... valuesList)
```

Is it a good practice to define an API method like this ? The reason I am asking because the compiler throws a warning , "Type safety: A generic array of List is created for a varargs parameter".

Please provide your comments and suggestions.

Comment: "Type safety: A generic array of List is created for a varargs parameter" why? are you sure? which java version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Krithika,

firstly the issue depends from the version used and will change again in future version.

IMHO it is NOT an issue about "good practice", it is a "**vulnerability**" of varargs. Since, varargs (as you know) is an array and Java does not permit the creation of arrays of parameterized types, the compiler converts the varargs formal parameter to `Object[]` ( List[] instead of List[] in the given case) elements losing the "real type".

Then, having taken note of this issue, **use varargs only for primitive type when you finish the write API**. **However**, Java knows this issue: see also the dedicated annotation on java 7 `@SafeVarargs`

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/SafeVarargs.html

**if java "admits it", this way should be acceptable.**

Finally, see the [official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/non-reifiable-varargs.html).

Comment: Yes ... Please see my edited question.I thought defining like will be easier for the API user.But I am reconsidering whether to expose a map instead of this approach

Comment: "the compiler converts the varargs formal parameter to Object[]" Not true. Here it will be `List[]`

Comment: right sorry to List[] instead of List<String>[] in this case, but the problem is the same